# vaadin focus replaced component

Tags: java, vaadin

I use replaceComponent(oldButton, newTextField) in button click listener, after that operation button is replaced by text field, but I have to click on it to be able to input text.

I want to click button and write text into text field without clicking on text field. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to request focus on the new TextField, using the [AbstractField#focus()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#focus%28%29) method, i.e.

```
replaceComponent(oldButton, newTextfield)
newTextField.focus();
```